# Android how to draw shape centered in view

Tags: android, kotlin, canvas, android-custom-view

I have multiple instances of a custom view where I'm trying to draw custom shapes using the center values from the view. The problem is that I've been unsuccessful when trying to get the center and drawing shapes on it, here is the result from the code below, you can see that the black squares are not properly centered in each one of the 4 squares:

[image]

```
class MyCustomView
constructor(context: Context,
            attrs: AttributeSet? = null
) : View(context, attrs) {

    private var center = PointF(0f, 0f)

    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        center.set(w / 2f, h / 2f)
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        val squareDimension = 100F
        val halfDimension = squareDimension / 2
        if (center.x == 0F || center.y == 0F) {
            center = PointF(width / 2F, height / 2F)
        }

        val paint = Paint()

        paint.color = Color.rgb(
            0,
            0,
            0)

        canvas.drawRect(
            center.x - halfDimension,
            center.y - halfDimension,
            center.x + halfDimension,
            center.y + halfDimension,
            paint)
    }

}
```

Android my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/second"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/third"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
        <MyCustomView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/first"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/second"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent">
        <MyCustomView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/third"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/fourth"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/first"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent">
        <MyCustomView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fourth"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/third"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/second"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        >
        <MyCustomView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

How can I draw the shape properly in the center of each view?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your views, `MyCustomView` and its parent are set to `wrap_content`. It is also the `LinearLayout`s whose bounds you see in the screen. If you inspect your views, it's likely that `MyCustomView`s are not actually where you expect.

Your options:

1. Make `LinearLayout` widths and heights `0dp` (though from the constraints this isn't required) and make `MyCustomView` widths and heights `match_parent`.
2. Remove `LinearLayout`s altogether and replace them with `MyCustomView`. The parent is currently redundant, though you may have a use for it later on.

In terms of your class, things look good, though I would have a single pointf only (`val`), create the paint globally and not on each draw, and avoid mutating the point during `onDraw`. You can optionally compute a `RectF` during `onSizeChanged` and avoid any further computation during `onDraw`